# Populating text box with string date-time without the time

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a table that holds a datetime field. I have put that into a datakey and on pageload and select from gridview it will populate the textbox with the datetime from the table in the database. I do not want the time. In the grid view I have already gotten rid of the time but when i populate the textbox I can not get rid of it. Any suggestions? here is my code: (I need both the PurchaseDate and WarrantyDate to show only the date without the time)

```
private void PopulateForm(int index)
    {

        var dataKey = grdvwAssetGrid.DataKeys[index];

        if (dataKey != null)
            AssetId = (int)dataKey["Id"];
        if (dataKey != null)
            LocationId = (int)dataKey["LocationId"];
        if (dataKey != null)
            txtVendor.Text = (string)dataKey["Vendor"];
        if (dataKey != null)
            txtSerialNumber.Text = (string)dataKey["SerialNumber"];
        if (dataKey != null)
            txtDescription.Text = (string)dataKey["Description"];
        if (dataKey != null)
            txtType.Text = (string)dataKey["Type"];
        if (dataKey != null)
            txtPrimaryUser.Text = (string)dataKey["PrimaryUser"];
        if (dataKey != null)
            txtPurchaseDate.Text = dataKey["PurchaseDate"].ToString();
        if (dataKey != null)
            txtWarrantyDate.Text = dataKey["WarrantyExpDate"].ToString();
    }
```

In the gridview I did this to change the datetime to only the date:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="PurchaseDate" HeaderText="Purchase Date" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="WarrantyExpDate" HeaderText="Warranty Date" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ToShortDateString()` instead of `ToString()`.

OR

`ToString("d")`, which is the format for a short date string.

UPDATE:

Cast your value to `DateTime` object, like this:

```
if (dataKey != null)
    txtPurchaseDate.Text = ((DateTime)dataKey["PurchaseDate"]).ToShortDateString();
if (dataKey != null)
    txtWarrantyDate.Text = ((DateTime)dataKey["WarrantyExpDate"]).ToString("d");
```

Comment: I tried that. It can not resolve the symbol ToShortDateString()

Comment: See `UPDATE:` in answer.

Comment: I tried that and I get this error : Error 3 The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type

Comment: @JoshuaJohnson - updated again, sorry switching between too many things at once. Forgot that `DateTime` is a structure, so you have to use the regular cast syntax.

Comment: Try parenthenses around the quantity to cast, see updated answer again.

Comment: That last update that you did with the extra parentheses worked perfect. I had tried this for about 2 hours and still could not get it to work but I did not have the extra parentheses. Thank you very much. You are amazing!!!!

Comment: @JoshuaJohnson - not amazing, but I appreciate the kind words. Glad it is working and it always easier to help when you have code to show. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have [ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) along with all possible formats you can supply to [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
txtPurchaseDate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(dataKey["PurchaseDate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```